# Instance group to recreate with different name

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to configure an instance group manager to create a brand new instance with a new name when one is unhealthy instead of using the same name?

The motivation is that we'ere using a distributed cluster (GlusterFS), and when an instance is recreated with the same name but missing he state it causes a split-brain scenario that is difficult to heal.

Any other workarounds are welcome.

Comment: GlusterFS can't be based on something else than the instance name? For example, the metadata?

Comment: When a MIG creates a new instance based on a template, a new instance name is generated. Do you mean "hostname"?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Not sure how that's that.

Comment: @TravisWebb A new instance is OK. But when one is unhealthy and is recreated it has a new name